# How to redefine the spacing between entries in the List of Figures without using the tocloft package?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, header-footer, tocloft

There are a few posts about how to redefine the spacing in the LOF, but most use packages like `tocloft`, which changes the page number position to `center` in the frontmatter instead of the setting `\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}`.

I want to use a command like:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1.0 ex}
```

or

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{1.0 ex}
```

to set the space between list entries.

So how to redefine the spacing of the list of figures and tables for the `book` or `article` class, without changing the default page number position?

Comment: Thanks, using `\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}` command solves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main reason for not using the `tocloft` package is its effect on the page numbering style of lists such as the Table of Contents and the List of Figures, you could address this issue by issuing the command

```
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
```

in the preamble (after loading the `tocloft` package, of course). As you've discovered, the default page style used by `tocloft` is indeed "plain".

Assuming you do choose to work with the `tocloft` package, the main length parameters available to affect the spacing between list items are `\cftparskip` and `cftbeforeXskip`, where `X` can be `part`, `chapter`, `sec`, `subsec`, `subsubsec`, `para`, `subpara`, `fig`, `subfig`, `tab`, and `subtab`. The default value of these parameters is `0pt`. The `\cftparskip` and `\cftbeforeXskip` macros can be changed via `\setlength` commands.